# Weka XRFFSaver including missing sparse values

Tags: weka

I'm using the XRFFSaver class in the current weka dev version.  I'm using xrff rather than arff as I have extremely sparse data and the [specs here](http://weka.wikispaces.com/XRFF) indicate that sparse instances are handled nicely and efficiently (i.e. not included in output).

However using XRFFSaver they are included in the output like this:

```
<value index="1" missing="yes"/>
<value index="2" missing="yes"/>
...
```

Which defeats the purpose of the whole exercise.  Anyone know if this is operator error or will I need to write my own saver?

I had a quick look at the source and I could not find any way of toggling this behaviour in either XRFFSaver or XMLInstances, however it was a quick look.

tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I quickly hacked up a solution to this:

Note: This is in C# (I use [weka through ikvm](http://weka.wikispaces.com/IKVM+with+Weka+tutorial)).  However, this should be very simple for anyone to convert to Java.
Note2: The only important line is this one: `if (sparse) continue` which I also highlighted below with comments.  Everything else is a straight copy of the weka source which I found through grepcode and google.  Not even sure if its the latest version I copied so please use with discretion.

I also tested to ensure that the standard XRFFLoader handles this correctly and it appears it does.

Tnx

```
  // Usage
  var saver = new EfficientXRFFSaver();
  saver.setCompressOutput(file.EndsWith(".gz"));
  saver.setInstances(Instances);
  saver.setFile(new java.io.File(file));
  saver.writeBatch();

  // Implementation
  public class EfficientXRFFSaver : XRFFSaver
  {
    public override void resetOptions() {
      base.resetOptions();
      setFileExtension(getCompressOutput() ? XRFFLoader.FILE_EXTENSION_COMPRESSED : XRFFLoader.FILE_EXTENSION);

      try { m_XMLInstances = new EfficientXMLInstances(); } 
      catch { m_XMLInstances = null; }
    }
  }

  public class EfficientXMLInstances : XMLInstances
  {
    protected override void addInstance(Element parent, Instance inst) {      
      var node = m_Document.createElement(TAG_INSTANCE);
      parent.appendChild(node);

      var sparse = inst is SparseInstance;
      if (sparse) { node.setAttribute(ATT_TYPE, VAL_SPARSE); }
      if (inst.weight() != 1.0) { node.setAttribute(ATT_WEIGHT, Utils.doubleToString(inst.weight(), m_Precision)); }
      for (var i = 0; i < inst.numValues(); i++) {
        var index = inst.index(i);

        var value = m_Document.createElement(TAG_VALUE);        
        if (inst.isMissing(index)) {

          // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
          // !!!!!!!!!! IMPORTANT !!!!!!!!!!!!!
          // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
          // This line will not add this element if its missing and sparse.
          if (sparse) continue;
          value.setAttribute(ATT_MISSING, VAL_YES);
        } else {
          if (inst.attribute(index).isRelationValued()) {
            var child = m_Document.createElement(TAG_INSTANCES);
            value.appendChild(child);
            for (var n = 0; n < inst.relationalValue(i).numInstances(); n++) {
              addInstance(child, inst.relationalValue(i).instance(n));
            }
          } else {
            value.appendChild(inst.attribute(index).type() == weka.core.Attribute.NUMERIC ? 
                m_Document.createTextNode(Utils.doubleToString(inst.value(index), m_Precision)) : 
                m_Document.createTextNode(validContent(inst.stringValue(index))));
          }
        }
        node.appendChild(value);
        if (sparse) { value.setAttribute(ATT_INDEX, "" + (index + 1)); }
      }
    }
  }
```